# Python: Fuzzywuzzy not working for foreign characters

Tags: python, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzywuzzy

When I try a simple fuzzywuzzy expression with foreign characters, I get erroneous results using the process.extractOne method (I've tried with and without the u):

```
>>> choices= [u"הלכות חנוכה",u"הלכות פורים",u"הלכות סוכה"]
>>> process.extractOne("הלכות סוכה", choices)
(u'\u05d4\u05dc\u05db\u05d5\u05ea \u05d7\u05e0\u05d5\u05db\u05d4', 0)
```

Yet it runs smoothly for fuzz.ratio:

```
>>> fuzz.ratio("הלכות ראש השנה", "הלכות תעניות")
69
```

And the same code works great for regular characters:

```
>>> choices= ['this','that','those']
>>> process.extractOne("these", choices)
('those', 80)
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `fuzz.ratio` as in the `scorer=` argument and add the u in front of the string you're trying to match for.

Below works:

`choices= [u"הלכות חנוכה",u"הלכות פורים",u"הלכות סוכה"]
process.extractOne(u"הלכות סוכה", choices, scorer=fuzz.ratio)`

(u'\u05d4\u05dc\u05db\u05d5\u05ea \u05e1\u05d5\u05db\u05d4', 100)

And others give the same score as well:

`choices= [u"הלכות חנוכה",u"הלכות פורים",u"הלכות סוכה"]
process.extract(u"הלכות סוכה", choices, scorer=fuzz.ratio)`

[(u'\u05d4\u05dc\u05db\u05d5\u05ea \u05e1\u05d5\u05db\u05d4', 100),
 (u'\u05d4\u05dc\u05db\u05d5\u05ea \u05d7\u05e0\u05d5\u05db\u05d4', 86),
 (u'\u05d4\u05dc\u05db\u05d5\u05ea \u05e4\u05d5\u05e8\u05d9\u05dd', 67)]

Fuzzywuzzy version: fuzzywuzzy 0.7.0 & Python 2.7x